# Magento 2: Inline edit in a Grid showing 503 error

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, grid, inline

[image]

Working on inline edit showing 503 error, can't find it out.

in `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_index_listing.xml` file for inline edit added below code

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">product_index_listing.product_index_listing.product_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">product_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="product/index/inlineEdit"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: this means that there is a problem with your `inlineEdit`action. Try enabling error reporting and check using firebug or developer tools on chrome or IE for the response from the ajax call to the inline edit save action.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "product_index_columns.ids" instead of "product_columns.ids

i.e.,

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">product_index_listing.product_index_listing.product_index_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">product_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="product/index/inlineEdit"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: hi @ dilip's i am also facing the same issue please help me thanks https://prnt.sc/g3ue8o

Comment: please refer the link below https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187731/magento-2-admin-grid-edit-inline