# Magento 2 admin grid edit inline?

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, grid, custom, github

i have used the below  **magento 2 custom extension** for creating **admin grid**. its working fine as of now but i am unable to edit inline, getting **500 internal error.**

did u anyone face the issue while using this extension. please suggest me thanks

[Reference Link-1](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-sample-module)

[Reference Link-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154828/magento-2-inline-edit-in-a-grid-showing-503-error)

**Screenshot:**

http://prntscr.com/g3ue8o

Comment: Check in console->networkTab for ajax calling after click on save and check you controller working or not.

Comment: Thanks @price i am getting an error as shown this screenshot http://prntscr.com/g49md6